# VKSdk как задать делегата в Swift?

Tags: ios, vkontakte-api, swift

Я пытаюсь заставить работать вк сдк на свифте. Согласно документации, написанное для обжеткив-с, нужно сделать такие шаги

```
VKSdk *sdkInstance = [VKSdk initializeWithAppId:YOUR_APP_ID];
[sdkInstance registerDelegate:delegate];
[sdkInstance setUiDelegate:uiDelegate];
```

Я пытаюсь сделать вот так

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    VKSdk.initializeWithAppId("1111111")
    VKSdk.registerDelegate(self)
}
```

Но получаю ошибку

> Cannot convert value of type "ViewController" to expected argument type "VKSdk"

Как задать делегат правильно?

Answer (score 1):

В VkSdk версии 1.2: `VKSdk.initializeWithDelegate(self, andAppId: "1111111")`

В VkSdk c версии 1.3 так:

`let sdk = VKSdk.initializeWithAppId("1111111")
 sdk.registerDelegate(self)`

И в классе нужно прописать что ты реализуешь протокол `VKSdkDelegate`, и реализовать обязательные методы

Comment: методы я реализую, на протокол подписан. а вызов с инициализацией делегата - из старого сдк, сейчас вызов происходит по другому, как указано у меня в посте

Comment: поправил ответ в соответствии новому VkSdk

Comment: пробовал так тоже, ругается :( https://s.mail.ru/5W5jRvbDCaLA/img-2015-11-02-14-25-31.png

Comment: скиньте код класса всего, тогда можно будет понять почему ругается. В моем проекте всё отлично работает, только что проверил, обновил VkSdk до последней версии и внес изменения которые написал выше, никаких ошибок нет.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/seccipPG

Comment: попробуйте сделать импорт: import VK_ios_sdk

Comment: не, не импортит. вообще он без импорта видит все методы ВК и отображает их в автокомплите синтаксиса

Comment: очень странно, у меня например без импорта не видит методы фреймворка. Устанавливал через Cocoapods. Может фреймворк не правильно установлен? Вот так у меня сделано: http://s004.radikal.ru/i205/1511/9c/c46a79d376f3.png

Answer (score 1):

```
VKSdk.initializeWithAppId("1111111")
VKSdk.instance().uiDelegate = self       
VKSdk.instance().registerDelegate(self)
```

Answer (score -1):

попробуй добавить протокол `VKSdkUIDelegate` для него него можно записать `sdk.setUIDelegate(self)`

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Поясните, на чем основано ваше утверждение?